# How to get data out of loop?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, programming, arduino-ide

hi i wrote a code(i modified it actually, please forgive me, im in a mess please help me if you can) for my esp8266 to serial communicate with at tiny 85 ,it will monitor switch state and publish accordingly. now i want to write a code where it wont publish but whenever the serial is available i want it to directly take it and digital write in void callback.

```
//ItKindaWorks - Creative Commons 2016
//github.com/ItKindaWorks
//
//Requires PubSubClient found here: https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient
//
//ESP8266 Simple MQTT light controller


#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int LED3 = 12;
int LED4 = 14;
int LED2 = 13;
int LED1 = 15;

bool switch1;
bool switch2;
bool switch3;
bool switch4;
char data ;
// the number of the pushbutton pin

//EDIT THESE LINES TO MATCH YOUR SETUP

#define MQTT_SERVER "192.168.0.223"
const char* ssid = "TACHYON_HOME";
const char* password = "qwertyui";

//LED on ESP8266 GPIO2

char* lightTopic = "/test/light1";
char* lightTopic1 = "/test/light2";
char* lightTopic2 = "/test/light3";
char* lightTopic3 = "/test/light4";


WiFiClient wifiClient;
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
PubSubClient client(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, callback, wifiClient);

void setup() {
  //initialize the light as an output and set to LOW (off)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED3 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED1 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2 , OUTPUT);
 
    delay(100);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

 
   
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
   
}



void loop(){
  //reconnect if connection is lost
  if (!client.connected() && WiFi.status() == 3) {reconnect();}

  //maintain MQTT connection
  client.loop();

  //MUST delay to allow ESP8266 WIFI functions to run
  delay(10);
   if (Serial.available()>0) /* If data available at serial port, enter if loop */
  {
    data = Serial.read(); /* Read data present at serial port */
    /* Print string with \r\n */
    Serial.print(data); /* Print data received */
    if (data == 'q') {
      client.publish(lightTopic,"1");
   
    }
else  if (data == 'w') {
      client.publish(lightTopic,"0");
    }
 else  if (data == 'e') {
      client.publish(lightTopic1,"1");
    }
    else if (data == 'r') {
      client.publish(lightTopic1,"0");
   
    }
     else if (data == 't') {
      client.publish(lightTopic2,"1");
   
    }
     else if  (data == 'y') {
      client.publish(lightTopic2,"0");
   
    }
     else if (data == 'u') {
      client.publish(lightTopic3,"1");
   
    }
     else if  (data == 'i') {
      client.publish(lightTopic3,"0");
   
    }
   
       
     
  }
}


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  //convert topic to string to make it easier to work with
  String topicStr = topic;

  //Print out some debugging info
  Serial.println("Callback update.");
  Serial.print("Topic: ");
  Serial.println(topicStr);

 

 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic)){

   if(payload[0] == '1'){
      digitalWrite(LED1 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'){
      digitalWrite(LED1 , LOW);
    }
 }
 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic1)){

   if(payload[0] == '1'){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , LOW);
    }
 }
 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic2)){

   if(payload[0] == '1'){
      digitalWrite(LED3 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'){
      digitalWrite(LED3 , LOW);
    }
 }
  if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic3)){

   if(payload[0] == '1'){
      digitalWrite(LED4 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'){
      digitalWrite(LED4 , LOW);
    }
  }
 
}






void reconnect() {

  //attempt to connect to the wifi if connection is lost
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    //debug printing
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    //loop while we wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    //print out some more debug once connected
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }

  //make sure we are connected to WIFI before attemping to reconnect to MQTT
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
  // Loop until we're reconnected to the MQTT server
    while (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");

      // Generate client name based on MAC address and last 8 bits of microsecond counter
      String clientName;
      clientName += "esp8266-";
      uint8_t mac[6];
      WiFi.macAddress(mac);
      clientName += macToStr(mac);

      //if connected, subscribe to the topic(s) we want to be notified about
      if (client.connect((char*) clientName.c_str())) {
        Serial.print("\tMTQQ Connected");
        client.subscribe(lightTopic);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic1);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic2);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic3);
   
       
      }

      //otherwise print failed for debugging
      else{Serial.println("\tFailed."); abort();}
    }
  }
}

//generate unique name from MAC addr
String macToStr(const uint8_t* mac){

  String result;

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    result += String(mac[i], 16);

    if (i < 5){
      result += ':';
    }
  }

  return result;
}


//////////////////i want to write some thing like///////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////
if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic1)||Serial.available()>0){

   if(payload[0] == '1'|| data =q){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'|| data = w){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , LOW);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: how to do that i tried it but it isnt working its only taking data from mqtt but not from the switch state

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you want to achieve. And show your code! You wrote “_I wrote a code for my esp8266_”, yet the code you are showing is visibly not something _you_ wrote. You also wrote you want “_a code where it wont publish_”: if it won't publish, then what interactions should it have with the MQTT server? Should it do MQTT at all? If not, why are you showing a sketch that is al about MQTT?

Comment: sorry i modified this code *correction* i want it to monitor the switches and turn off devices with mqtt and without mqtt too. i want it to control relays even when the network is off.

Comment: your post still says that you wrote the code

Answer (score 0):

So you want your program to react to both MQTT and serial messages. You
wrote this snippet:

```cpp
if (topicStr.equals(lightTopic1) || Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (payload[0] == '1' || data = q) {
        digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
    }
    else if (payload[0] == '0' || data = w) {
        digitalWrite(LED2 , LOW);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Other than a couple of syntactic problems (you mean `data == 'q'`, not
`data = q`), the logic is not appropriate. This is because:

- The test `payload[0] == '1'` only makes sense in the context of
  parsing an MQTT message, otherwise `payload` cannot be meaningfully
  defined.
- For the same reason, the test `data == 'q'` only makes sense in the
  context of parsing a serial command.

Since MQTT and serial use completely different commands, you will have
to handle them independently. You can keep the MQTT callback as is, and
implement the parser for the serial commands. Maybe something like:

```cpp
if (Serial.available()) {
    char command = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(command);  // echo to the serial port
    switch (command) {
        case 'q':
            digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
            break;
        case 'w':
            digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
            break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use an `if ... else if ...` chain if you are not
comfortable with the `switch` syntax.

I personally would rather store the topic names, LED pins and serial
commands in an array of structs, and loop through the array in both the
MQTT callback and the serial parser. But I assume that may be too
advanced for your current programming level, so maybe just stick with
the simple, albeit verbose solution.